# Python convert audio files to MP3

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, mp3, lame

I'm trying to write a small utility that get as input an m4a/ogg file and converts it to a MP3 audio file.
My main goal is not to use any third party binaries such as 'Lame' or 'ffmpeg'.
I read allot about PyMedia and such, but my knowledge on audio codecs is very poor.
Can any one help me and give me an elegant cross platform solution?
Thanks!

EDIT:
meanwhile I know it is very basic but this is my code :

```
import sys

def convert2mp3(input_file):
    .....
    some magic...
    ...
    return mp3file

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print "%prog Usage: %s <input file>"
        sys.exit()

    convert2mp3(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: "My main goal is not to use any third party binaries such as 'Lame' or 'ffmpeg'. I read allot about PyMedia and such, but my knowledge on audio codecs is very poor."  You want to invent your own codec, ignoring **decades** of work that has been done on existing codecs?  And, you have no knowledge of how they work today?  That's an impossible project, I'm afraid.

Comment: My intention is not to reinvent the wheel. I'm just asking if any one knows a native python library that does that (I mean not to just call 'ffmpeg' on the command line ...)

Answer (score 1):

Give `PyMedia` a Google search, install it, and use [this](http://pymedia.org/tut/recode_audio.html) tutorial to recode the audio.

Comment: Thanks. I already got through that example, though didnt understand why it doesn't work. Can you try it and tell if your succeeding?

Comment: I'm no really sure what you mean, but in effect, audio files are simply compressed binary. `PyMedia` allows the extraction of said binary for the purpose of encryption and recompression.

Comment: Forgive me for not fully understanding what you mean, but I know audio files are binaries arranged in a unique specific way. It doesn't change that fact that one; that script doesn't work and 2; I didn't get the help I needed.

Comment: The tutorial uses different file formats. Did you change to the appropriate formats and add your own file names in the placeholders?